# Round hundreds, thousands, lack in to H, T, L

Tags: php

Is there any PHP function which convert

100 = 1H
1000 = 10H
10000 = 10T
100000 = 1L

and so on

Comment: Which of the existing PHP functions didn't suit your needs? What unit of measurement is that?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Is this a common notation? It looks pretty ideosyncratic to me. I could imagine having a standard function for kilo, mega, tera, etc. prefixes, but I don't think there is one for that, either.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Please help the OP to improve the question.

Comment: He asked if there's a function to do this, there isn't one. The rest is editorializing about why there isn't one, since I didn't want to post just "No".